# Router in Extjs 5.1

Tags: extjs

I want to access My Extjs application internal url from other Application Hyperlink click which redirect to my application. Someone told me to use router is router. Is this router safe from security point of view?

Comment: What you mean by security? Router is basically a handler for the URL's hashbang part change event.

Comment: Also security on client side is really only for the ux. Whatever concerns sensitive / authentication required data, should be managed on the server's side.